# Is there a way for my Windows 10 PC to detect when my TV display wakes up in a script?

Tags: windows-10, display, power-management

I have my PC connected to a TV over HDMI. In Windows my power plan is set to turn off the display (or actually stop sending the signal) after x minutes of inactivity. My TV is set to turn off after x minutes of no signal.

The problem is that when I wake the display on Windows side by moving a mouse, the signal is back on, but that doesn't turn the TV back on. I can however run a script that will use my wifi connected remote to turn the TV back on.

**How can I detect the display waking up and run a command when that happens?**

Note: I don't mean full Windows wake up, just the display waking up.